# Adding various type of components into a JComponent reference array

Tags: java, reference, instantiation, jcomponent

I have a JComponent reference like `JComponent allComp[];` 
Now I want to every element of this array holds different type of component like below,

`allComp[0] = new JComboBox();`

`allComp[1] = new JButton();`

`allComp[2] = new JMonthChooser();`

I am trying and getting Null Pointer exception. Is this possible?? If possible how??
Please help me in this issue.
Thanks advance

Comment: Did you remember to initialise the array ie allComp = new JComponent[3]? I'd also recommend the use of a List instead ;)

Comment: Oh, yeah...got it..Actually editor was not giving suggestion of adding. That's why I overlooked. It seems now a silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have not initialized `allComp` and it's `null`.

```
JComponent allComp[] = new JComponent[MAX_COMPONENTS];
```

Anyway, it is advisable to use a `List` instead of an array if you don't know beforehand the number of components.

```
List<JComponent> allComp = new ArrayList<>();
allComp.add(new JComboBox());
allComp.add(new JButton());
allComp.add(new JMonthChooser());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the array object itself:

```
JComponent[] allComp = new JComponent[ARRAYSIZE];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you haven't initialized the array

```
int arraySize = 20;
JComponent allComp[] = new JComponent[arraySize];
```

Doing something like

```
JComponent allComp[]
```

Only "declares" the object, which is sort of like a promise "somewhere in this code I will use this object, but I haven't decided what I want it to be yet, so I'm leaving it undefined".

"Initialization" is what you need to do to actually create the object. Usually you do this with the

```
new
```

keyword.